# What are the job opportunities in askubuntu

Tags: support

I am extremely interested in this Q&A site and I would like to contribute seriously. But I also need to earn money to feed myself and the two cannot possibly go along.

So I would like to know if there is any possibility of earning over here?

Comment: You can only earn reputations, badges here as far as I Know, unless you're a SE employee

Comment: how to become SE employee?

Comment: Why ask about SE on AU? People that make money and that are on AU are Canonical employees.

Comment: and how to become canonical employee?

Comment: @rancho stop it I'mma pee my shorts lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What Rinzwind says is true. Though I'd just like to add that SE do have job openings which you can apply for.

You check them out by clicking the [work here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) link in the footer of any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Since this is Ask Ubuntu, I thought I should also mention that you can also apply for a job at Canonical (The company behind Ubuntu). You can check those job opportunities by clicking the [careers](http://www.canonical.com/careers) link in the footer of [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 14):

None whatsoever.

This is a community driven website where volunteers do the work.

No money to be made whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Minding the existing answers, I would like to point out that in a perhaps not so remote future, sites that rely on voluntary contributions and reputation like this one **could be monetised** in such a way that rancho and other can earn money from their reputation.

How? The answer lays in the **blockchain!**

In fact, you might have heard of [Steem.it](http://www.steemit.com), a "social network" where you earn digital money from writing and moderating. The more you contribute and vote, the more you earn. It is not really a Q&A forum but in principle the dynamic could be applied to a Q&A setting.

I made a [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329768/is-the-future-of-qa-sites-like-se-in-the-blockchain?noredirect=1#comment374045_329768) in the Meta of SE which sadly received little attention/interest, probably because of the strong feelings against the idea.

Now, this is just a thought-provoking idea. Personally, I prefer it as it is now, but so many things have become monetized against people's will.